# Microsoft.AspNet.Providers errors after uninstalling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I had installed the package: `Microsoft.AspNet.Providers` and this in turn added a folder named `Bin` to the project. But I faced a problem in customizing the profile (properties not added to the database) comparing this folder to the tutorial i'm following, I found that there was a missing file in the Bin folder. I deleted the folder and reinstalled the package. but when I open the page in the browser I end up with these pages:
[image]

[image]

The `Bin` folder is not exist any more. How to restore it?

Comment: Error  says few DLL missing... clean and reinstall packages and rebuild your solution may work

Comment: follow these link, it will resolve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969642/infrastucture-does-not-exist-in-system-data-entity

Answer (score 2):

We have answers for the above questions in SO. Refer below links.

[Visual Studio 2012 MVC build error: The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796205/visual-studio-2012-mvc-build-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-infrastructure)

[The namespace name Infrastructure does not exist in a namespace system.data.entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577157/the-namespace-name-infrastructure-does-not-exist-in-a-namespace-system-data-enti)